Firebase App Distribution displays the actual Play Store page instead of the latest build
Same problem as this ticket here
New Uploads in Firebase App Distribution Cannot be Downloaded Suddenly
It won't open the build download page, but the live Google play store

Re-installing the app distribution
Clear data and cache from app distribution
Clear data and cache from Google Play store
Restart the device

None of this worked, and the previus ticked doesn't show how to get this fixed
